# How can open an image by asking the path of it using pillow (python)?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to pass the path of an image and then opening it but i get this error for this line `image = Image.open(path)`:

> AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

```
from PIL import Image
from tkinter import *

class Menu:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Image")
        self.image_entry = Entry(root)
        self.image_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
        image_label = Label(root,text = "Enter the path of the image").grid(row=0)


        images = Button(root,text="Show",command=lambda:[self.show(self.image_entry)]).grid(row=1,column=1)

        root.mainloop()


   def show(self,image_entry):
        path=image_entry.get()
        image = Image.open(path)
        image.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `Image` imported from PIL is being overwritten by the variable `Image` imported from Tkinter.

Possible solutions, in descending order of best-practice-ness:

- Don't import things from tkinter using `import *`. Try importing only the names you need, for example `from tkinter import Entry, Label, Button, Tk`.
- Choose an alias for PIL's `Image` that doesn't conflict with Tkinter's `Image`. For example, `from PIL import Image as PILImage`.
- Switch the order of your imports so PIL's `Image` overwrites Tkinter's `Image`, instead of the other way around.